# ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'torch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0'

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, torch

I wanted to create a docker image to run my code that needs to run a DNN on GPU. Inside of Dockerfile, I want to install requirements.txt using pip. The requirement file includes:

```
pandas
matplotlib
swig
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch_stable.html
torch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch_stable.html
```

When I want to build the image I encounter this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'torch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0' (from line 5 of requirements.txt)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 23.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I upgraded pip in my local machine as it is written in warning message but I still get this error.
Any helps?

As the second question, Do I anything more (requirements) to run a DNN on GPU?

Comment: Are `torch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0` on the same line in the requirements file?  I think they have to be on separate lines.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes you are right, thanks. When I fixed it, I got another error: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement." My cuda version is 10.1. I also tried torch==1.7.0 torchvision==0.8.1, but I still get the same error about satisfying the requirement! Any clue?

Comment: @Hami that should be posted as a separate question. You should also post an answer to this question now that the issue is solved.